# workspaces環境をawscli・terraformで作成する際、"ResourceNotFound.User"となる。

Tags: aws, aws-cli

AWS Directory ServiceでSimple_ADを土台に
workspaces環境をawscli・terraformで作成したいのですが、
ユーザの指定は出来ても、作成をする方法がマネージドコンソールでしか不可能なので、
"ResourceNotFound.User"が発生します。

workspaces環境のユーザを「ユーザー名」「名」「姓」「E メール」を指定して作成する方法が見当たらないため
完全に自動化することは不可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraformのドキュメントを見る限り、中のユーザの管理までは現状サポートしていないようなのでTerraformだけでそこまでやるのは無理だと思います。

一応、ファイルを用意してLDAP周りのコマンドでユーザ追加することができないこともないので、別途管理サーバなどからユーザを一括追加することはやろうと思えばできるんだとは思います。
https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/linux-simplead-management/